# How to group all scores by username in a table and display rank?

Tags: mysql, group-by, aggregate-functions

So I have a MySQL database

```
CREATE TABLE `all_time_earners` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `image` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `username` varchar(250) NOT NULL,
  `earnings` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `rank` int(11) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=6 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
```

this is what my table is like

```
id     username      earnings  rank
====================================================
1,          ken,       100,      0
2,          dave,       50,      0
3,          bob,       300,      0
4,          ken,       150,      0
5,          ken,       200,      0
```

I'm trying to GROUP BY username, but it won't show multiple entries for a user using

```
"SELECT * FROM all_time_earners GROUP BY username ORDER BY earnings DESC;"
```

The problem is that it doesn't sum up the earnings

1. Please could someone point me as to what i'm doing wrong?
2. How do I rank these users e.g: user with highest earnings has rank 1, next is rank 2, etc

Comment: This is probably the bug in MySQL 5.7.4 or older. This SQL query should not be valid, but old MySQL used to accept it.

Comment: Check out `sum()` and `rank()`.

Comment: Try `select sum(earnings) as e from table group by username order by e desc`

Comment: What version of MySQL? 5.x, or 8.x?

Comment: @user3783243 thanks

Comment: @TheImpaler i think 5.X

Answer (score 2):

With Mysql 5.7 I believe you can achieve what you want like this:

```
SELECT username, 
       SUM(earnings) AS totalEarnings
FROM all_time_earners ate
GROUP BY username
ORDER BY totalEarnings DESC;
```

And if you want to add the rank number:

```
SET @row_number = 0;

SELECT te.*, 
       @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS rank
FROM (
  SELECT username, 
         SUM(earnings) AS totalEarnings
  FROM all_time_earners ate
  GROUP BY username
  ORDER BY totalEarnings DESC
) te
```

Check it out in this [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/zjTwmH32hjcLApfGZN8E2/0)

Comment: Thanks, the first query works, but the second doesnt work in my code, but trying it out on dbfiddle I can see that it indeed works, but it sets dave(user with lower rank as rank 2)

Comment: @Drwho yes your correct, my mistake. Actually I think that a subquery is necessary.

Comment: Please what do you mean by a subquery, please am still new to sql and I don't really understand whats happening in the second code for rank

Comment: A subquery is the combination of two queries (maybe more). If you compare the two queries, you'll see the second one encloses the first in this query: `SELECT te.*, @row_number := @row_number + 1 AS rank FROM ( /* the subquery / first query */ ) te`. This means the second query runs on the result of the first one. Hope I've made myself clear, anyway here's more information https://www.w3resource.com/sql/subqueries/understanding-sql-subqueries.php

Comment: thanks, based on your explanation please heres a look of what I tried, but it breaks my whole code https://pastebin.com/eLD5cm3g

Comment: @Drwho The code `SET @row_number = 0;` is part o the query. Try placing it inside the prepare method before the select : `$stmt = $conn->prepare(“SET @row_number = 0; Select te.* ...`. Don’t forget to delete the `SET @row_number = 0` on line 18

Comment: I still wasnt able to execute the query, someone mentioned to me that prepare statement wont let that happen